How to display Google Pay in an iframe instead of in a popup window
Visit https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/guides/resources/demos in Chrome on Android (iOS untested) and click on the first example. You will get Google Pay in an iframe, as shown here:

Try the same example in any other browser (device or desktop PC) and Google Pay opens in a popup window.
I'm implementing Google Pay into a Cordova app and would need it to open in an iframe instead of a popup.
Is this a feature specific to the Chrome app or can it be implemented into other apps? (a permission that needs to be added maybe?) Or maybe it's as simple as some Google Pay Javascript code that allows it?
Thanks for any help!

have you tried opening it in a  instead of an  ?

The button and accompanying opening code is generated by Google's Javascript so I'm not even sure how that would be possible.

This has nothing todo with iframes. Your image shows the native Android Google Pay sheet. Automatic bridging to the native Android Google Pay sheet is only available for Chrome on Android. For your Cordova app you need to manually bridge to the Android Google Pay APIs. Something similar to this:
https://github.com/ZelCore-io/cordova-plugin-apple-pay-google-pay/blob/master/src/android/ApplePayGooglePay.java

Thanks @Domi. Looks like I've got some changes to implement.
